Understanding virtual memory via background jobs
Understanding virtual memory in Operating Systems: Concepts and Implementation
Unexpected behavior when running multiple instances of a memory allocation program.
I'm learning about operating systems and following the OSTEP (Operating Systems: Three Easy Pieces) textbook. I'm trying to understand memory virtualization by running multiple instances of a program simultaneously. Here's the code I'm working with:
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "common.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int *p = malloc(sizeof(int)); // a1
    assert(p != NULL);
    printf("(%d) address pointed to by p: %p\n", getpid(), p); // a2
    *p = 0; // a3
    while (1) {
        Spin(1);
        *p = *p + 1;
        printf("(%d) p: %d\n", getpid(), *p); // a4
    }
    return 0;
}

According to the textbook, when run with the command ./mem &; ./mem &, this program should demonstrate memory virtualization by running two instances simultaneously. The text states:

We see from the example that each running program has allocated memory at the same address (0x200000), and yet each seems to be updating the value at 0x200000 independently! It is as if each running program has its own private memory, instead of sharing the same physical memory with other running programs. Indeed, that is exactly what is happening here as the OS is virtualizing memory.

However, when I run this program locally, I get the following output:
PS C:\Users\malan\Desktop\os\Virtualizing_the_Cpu> ./mem &; ./mem

Id   Name             PSJobTypeName   State
--   ----             -------------   -----
13   Job13            BackgroundJob   Running
(8776) address pointed to by p: 007B1990
(8776) p:1
(8776) p:2
(8776) p:3
(8776) p:4
(8776) p:5
(8776) p:6
(8776) p:7
(8776) p:8
(8776) p:9
(8776) p:10
(8776) p:11
(8776) p:12
(8776) p:13

The two instances aren't running simultaneously as expected. What could be causing this behavior? Am I missing something in my setup or understanding of how this should work?
Additional information:

Operating System: Microsoft Windows 11 Home Single Language
Operating System Version:10.0.22631 N/A Build 22631
Compiler: gcc (MinGW.org GCC-6.3.0-1) 6.3.0


It is not "Virtualizing the CPU" - only using virtual memory which is something completely different

As an aside: Because you forgot the second & in ./mem &; ./mem, the second mem process runs in the  foreground and directly prints its output to the terminal. The output from the first one is the object that describes the PowerShell background job that the background operator, &, created.

I'm trying to guess, what is the reason of the #include "common.h" that you don't post, and the Spin(1); statemente (which I suppose uses a macro defined in the include file.  I'll try to run your case locally but I cannot ensure I get the results stated in the book.  I'll explain in that case.

Type it into bash and it will work.
& means run in background in bash, but it means something else in powershell; I'm surprised you didn't get an error message.

PowerShell (Core) 7 - unlike the built-in Windows PowerShell edition - does support postpositional & for starting background jobs on Windows. While these jobs work and are managed differently than in Bash, it is easy to adapt the command line to get the desired behavior.

The & at the end of a command is a bash directive (i.e. Linux / Unix command line) to run a program in the background.  It doesn't have this functionality under Windows.
The simplest thing to do is bring up two separate Command Prompts and run the program in each of them at roughly the same time.

PowerShell (Core) 7 - unlike the built-in Windows PowerShell edition - does support postpositional & for starting a background job on Windows, as evidenced by the output shown in the question. However, its output behavior differs from its Bash counterpart.

That said, it is easy to adapt the command line to get the desired behavior, and it
can even be made to work in Windows PowerShell, by using Start-Job in lieu of the background operator (&).

tl;dr
You're mistakenly using the syntax of POSIX-compatible shells such as bash.
In PowerShell (Core) 7 (which you're running), use the following instead:
(./mem &), (./mem &) | Receive-Job -Wait -AutoRemoveJob

In Windows PowerShell (the legacy, ships-with-Windows edition whose latest and last version is 5.1):
(Start-Job { ./mem }), (Start-Job { ./mem }) | Receive-Job -Wait -AutoRemoveJob


Differences between Bash and PowerShell jobs:

Indeed, the command line ./mem &; ./mem &  is meant for bash (or another POSIX-compatible shell such as zsh):

It creates two jobs that run in the background and (in addition to job control messages) send the process' output directly to the terminal, asynchronously.


The same command line works syntactically in PowerShell (Core) 7 too (albeit not in Windows PowerShell, which only supports Start-Job, see below), but functions differently there:

&, the postpositional background operator, is syntactic sugar for a Start-Job call (./mem & is short for Start-Job { ./mem })[1] and creates a PowerShell background job, and what these calls return is a job object that can be queried and managed with cmdlets such as Receive-Job.

While these jobs are loosely analogous to Bash jobs, there are important differences:

PowerShell jobs do not automatically print their output to the caller's terminal; instead, output is quietly collected behind the scenes, and can be retrieved on demand with Receive-Object

Completed jobs must be cleaned up (removed) manually, either via Remove-Job or, as shown above, by passing -AutoRemoveJob to Receive-Job (which also requires -Wait to synchronously wait for the job to complete, so that all of its output can be collected).







[1] There is one important difference, however: with Start-Job, you must use the $using: scope inside the script block ({ ... }) in order to reference variable values from the caller's scope, whereas with  & all variable references implicitly refer to the caller's variables. E.g., given a caller variable $foo = 'bar' the equivalent of Start-Job { "Caller's `$foo value: $using:foo" } is "Caller's `$foo value: $foo" &. However, the automatic $PID variable is - sensibly - special-cased and refers to the job's process ID (you can use $using:PID to refer to the caller's process ID). While not having to use $using: to refer to the caller's variables when using the background operator is undoubtedly convenient, it also creates ambiguity that can make job-specific variables inaccessible; see GitHub issue #14400 for a discussion.

What I get running your code is this (despite Spin() and common.h were not included in your post):
$ a.out & a.out &
[1] 163674
[2] 163675
(163674) address pointed to by p: 0x5b2b0f6912a0
(163675) address pointed to by p: 0x60fb95c322a0

As you see, both adresses are different.  Today, mostly in 64bit computers, the linux kernel (which I'm using to get your code running) randomizes the memory maps of the programs at dynamic loading, putting the different segments (text, data and stack) at random places in virtual memory.
This is done as a countermeasure against malware, and is not the used behaviour that was done at the time the book was written, and explains the output you observe.
Well, to reproduce the example as the book expects it, I can run your program in an old unix v7 (courtesy of Caldera, downloaded from www.tuhs.org) running on a pdp-11 simulator (simh), and let's see what happens:
[console]lcu@pdp-11 $ a.out & a.out &
100
101
[console]lcu@pdp-11 $ (100) address pointed to by p: 4104
(101) address pointed to by p: 4104
(100) p: 1
(101) p: 1
(100) p: 2
(101) p: 2
(100) p: 3

in this case you see that both processes (pids 100 and 101) show 4104 as the address.
Both processes have executed the same code in malloc() with identical virtual address spaces (the virtual address space of a pdp-11 is 64kb only) so malloc has returned the same address for the first malloc in the program.  But this doesn't happen today.
BTW the example is a bit unfortunate, because both programs store the same value at the same address... but in theory, if the address was the same, both programs should increment the same location making each program to count twice, instead of seeing both programs to show the same number at each printf, they should increment the number each and they would show consecutive numbers, not the same number both.
The actual program run had to be changed, as v7 has an old K&R compiler that doesn't support ANSI prototypes:
#include<stdio.h>
main()
{
    int *p = malloc(sizeof(int)); 
    printf("(%d) address pointed to by p: %d\n", getpid(), p); 
    *p = 0; 
    while (1) {

        sleep(1);
        *p = *p + 1;
        printf("(%d) p: %d\n", getpid(), *p); 
    }
    return 0;
}


The very premise of the question is the presence of memory virtualization; the only problem is with a failed attempt to run two processes of the  sample program concurrently, in order to demonstrate the feature, which boils down to confusion over shell syntax.

Hmmm.... yeah, but new linux does virtualization, and the addresses are different.  I was to demonstrate that with a pdp-11 (that has virtual memory too) but it could be valid to do it with linux kernel 1.2.13 and a 386 processor, with paged virtual memory, and you will get the same virtual address.
I explained the reason of getting different addresses, is not enough to you my explanation?

(Note that I'm not the OP). I missed that you're pointing out that the expected behavior as described in the referenced textbook no longer applies. So your answer is helpful (+1), but it doesn't address the OP's primary problem, which is one of shell syntax, as mentioned - and we can infer from what answer the OP accepted that they were (at least primarily) looking to solve that shell-syntax problem. Thus, my recommendation is to add a preamble to your answer for proper framing.
